# How can i use svg path on an img in css?

Tags: html, css, svg

so I want my image to be a shape of a blob and this is my code

```css
root{
  --blob: "M43.1,-67.8C56.1,-58.7,67,-8BQAzQwVETtFWGmAFZjAwNSYA7M4EczfocpPa2kZ6AiC1tVQuAhJTRjLG5Nkk4QqFWHxiKBdi6RuUFjC5zMhvhUyK7tatMA,56.1C5.8,55,-4.8,53.8,-18.3,53.8C-31.8,53.7,-4JUdGzvrMFDWrUUwY3toJATSeNwjn54LkCnKBPRzDuhzi5vSepHfUckJNxRL2gjkNrSqtCoRUrEDAgRwsQvVCjZbRyFTLRNyDmT1a1boZV2,-54.4,-53.1,-40.1,-61.7C-25.7,-70.2,-12.9,-80.4,1.1,-82C15,-83.7,30.1,-76.9,43.1,-67.8Z";

}

.img-class{
  clip-path: path(var(--blob));
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 200 200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path fill="#E8B224" d="M43.1,-67.8C56.1,-58.7,67,-8BQAzQwVETtFWGmAFZjAwNSYA7M4EczfocpPa2kZ6AiC1tVQuAhJTRjLG5Nkk4QqFWHxiKBdi6RuUFjC5zMhvhUyK7tatMA,56.1C5.8,55,-4.8,53.8,-18.3,53.8C-31.8,53.7,-4JUdGzvrMFDWrUUwY3toJATSeNwjn54LkCnKBPRzDuhzi5vSepHfUckJNxRL2gjkNrSqtCoRUrEDAgRwsQvVCjZbRyFTLRNyDmT1a1boZV2,-54.4,-53.1,-40.1,-61.7C-25.7,-70.2,-12.9,-80.4,1.1,-82C15,-83.7,30.1,-76.9,43.1,-67.8Z" transform="translate(100 100)" />
</svg>

<div class="img-class">
        <img src="img/img1.jpg" alt="img" />
</div>
```

but it doesn't work and I don't know what's wrong, I've seen a tutorial about it and this is exactly what they did.

update: so I kinda found out why it's not rendering, it's cus the SVG path is not the code I copied it keeps changing when I paste it, I don't know what to do but I copy a path but it pastes another code which is invalid,
like the path you're seeing in my codes is not the code I copied

Comment: your path’s d-property contains errors (see console errors in web inspector). It's not a valid path command array. Starting with `,-8BQAzQ`. Have you applied some special encoding or compression? Can you restore the original svg graphic?

Comment: Where is your SVG code from? I can't get it to render in Illustrator and I've never seen an SVG code like this. 

Here's an example of a blob type code: https://codepen.io/edgyDesign/pen/mNBjQr Your other code is fine but your SVG code itself isn't rendering anything.

Comment: so I kinda found out why it's not rendering, its cus the SVG path is not the code I copied it keeps changing when I paste it, I don't know what to do but I copy a path but it pastes another code which is invalid ,

Comment: Where are you copying it from? Are you pulling it out of an application like Illustrator or off the internet? Make sure it's the _raw_ code you're copying from a site.

Comment: It's a file, the file itself doesn't have any issue cus I can open it, the issue comes after I copy  it and  everything gets messed up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so the problem is the SVG code itself

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 200 200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path fill="#E8B224" d="M43.1,-67.8C56.1,-58.7,67,-8BQAzQwVETtFWGmAFZjAwNSYA7M4EczfocpPa2kZ6AiC1tVQuAhJTRjLG5Nkk4QqFWHxiKBdi6RuUFjC5zMhvhUyK7tatMA,56.1C5.8,55,-4.8,53.8,-18.3,53.8C-31.8,53.7,-4JUdGzvrMFDWrUUwY3toJATSeNwjn54LkCnKBPRzDuhzi5vSepHfUckJNxRL2gjkNrSqtCoRUrEDAgRwsQvVCjZbRyFTLRNyDmT1a1boZV2,-54.4,-53.1,-40.1,-61.7C-25.7,-70.2,-12.9,-80.4,1.1,-82C15,-83.7,30.1,-76.9,43.1,-67.8Z" transform="translate(100 100)" />
```

this code has an invalid path which is alright in the raw code/file
the problem begins when you try to copy it, and the reason for that is its juts too many characters, if you limit the characters you are copying to like 50 characters each time, you can prevent it from breaking, I don't know what is causing this maybe its a bug in windows clipboard or something but this is the solution I found to prevent this problem